# How to validate iText digital signature?

Tags: java, itext, signature

I'm working with digital signature validation, before writting about my problem I have to say that I found a lot of examples, some I believe are related to older iText version as it seems the methods no longer exists.

I'm using iText 5.8.8 and I got no exception at all, but when I check the validation status it returns always false and I don't know what to do, I started thinking there may be something wrong during the signature process but still don't know what.

Here it is the way I'm trying to check it:

```
public List<VerificationException> verifySignatures(byte[] assinado) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
// Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
List<VerificationException> errors = null;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(assinado);
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
    System.out.println("Document revision: " + af.getRevision(name) + " of " + af.getTotalRevisions());
    PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);

    if (!pk.verify()) {
    throw new GeneralSecurityException("some erros message... ");
    }
```

}

The point is every time I check pk.verify() it returns false. The name used to verify is setted during the signature process and it is something like this 
JOHN DOE:00000099999 Certificate

And here is how it is being signed:

```
public byte[] signPdfFirstTime(PrivateKey pk, Certificate[] chain, String providerName, String conteudoBase64, X509Certificate cert, String alias) throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);
document.open();

document.addTitle("Dummy PDF");
document.addSubject("Dummy PDF");
document.addKeywords("dummy, test");
document.addAuthor("John Doe ");
document.addCreator("John Doe ");
document.newPage();

document.add(new Paragraph("Title2"));

document.close();
String name = alias;

byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();


PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, bos, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason("REASON");
appearance.setLocation("CITY");
appearance.setCertificate(cert);

Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(550, 50, 610, 500);

 //here it goes the name
appearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, 1, name);

// Creating the signature
ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, providerName);
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
List<CrlClient> crlList = new ArrayList<CrlClient>();
crlList.add(new CrlClientOnline());

LtvVerification v = stamper.getLtvVerification();

OcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();

String url = CertificateUtil.getCRLURL(cert);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(new URL(url).openStream());
System.out.println("CRL valid until: " + crl.getNextUpdate());
System.out.println("Certificate revoked: " + crl.isRevoked(chain[0]));

if (crl.isRevoked(chain[0])) {

    throw new GeneralSecurityException("CERT REVOKED!");
}
else {
    MakeSignature.processCrl(cert, crlList);

    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return b;


}
}
```

The signature is being validated against the byte array returned from the method above

Comment: iText 5.8.8 does not exist (yet), perhaps you meant 5.5.8? (iText QA & Release Engineer here, so I should know)

Comment: Please share a sample signed document to reproduce the issue.

Comment: My bad, it is really 5.5.8 as you said. Well, there is no sample document to share because what is being signed is a document created on the first lines of signPdfFirstTime method. My main goal is to verify the signature on the server side and I couldn't get a simple String or something more simple than a document signed, so I thought it is a good idea to create a document in memory, get it signed then check the signature. Do you think it could be a bad approach? Thx for your attention.

Comment: I've just read your post in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846427/pdfpkcs7-verify-return-false  I could say it is almost the same thing, pk.verify always return false. I tried your work around but it didn't help as the value of param you suggested get by reflection is already null.

Comment: I tried to decompile PdfPKCS7 to see what is happening inside verify(), there is something about this: absentEncContDigestCompare = Arrays.equals(msgDigestBytes, this.digestAttr).... the result of comparing these 2 arrays are different so that the result of absentEncContDigestCompare flag is always false and then mess up everything. Now I'm looking for some reason and finally try to fix somewhere that result in 2 different arrays.

Comment: *Well, there is no sample document to share because what is being signed is a document created on the first lines of signPdfFirstTime method.* - but you surely can save and share such a sample file, can you not? I ask because the cause of such issues not too seldom is something very specific to the environment in which the signature was created, including properties of the private key, JRE, OS, ...

Comment: *I tried to decompile PdfPKCS7 to see what is happening inside verify()* - iText is open source. Thus, the obvious choice would have been to inspect the actual source which is hosted [here on github](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf). Additionally there are source artifacts retrievable via maven.

Comment: It is sad to say but I am not allowed to share the sample. Even during the development I'm using a real smart card/certificate with personal information of someone from our costumer team, so my manager forbid me to share as it could bring some problem to the company if the costumer finds out. Thx for all your help, even before this post you have been helping with other issues, thx for everything.