# PdfPKCS7 .verify() return false while signature verification

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, signature, verify

I have been working with itextSharp-5.5.5,  (5.5.10 / 5.5.13) Having issue with all version.

```
            TypeInfo typeInfo = typeof(PdfPKCS7).GetTypeInfo();
            FieldInfo rsaDataField = typeInfo.GetDeclaredField("RSAdata");
            Object rsadatafieldcontent = rsaDataField.GetValue(pkcs7);
            if (rsadatafieldcontent != null && ((byte[])rsadatafieldcontent).Length == 0)
            {
                _log.Info("Found zero-length encapsulated content: ignoring");
                rsaDataField.SetValue(pkcs7, null);
            } 
            if (pkcs7.Verifyc())    <------ **HERE return false**
            {
```

But Adobe Acrobat Reader say: Signed and all signatures are valid.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please also share a sample PDF you observe the issue with.

Comment: *'Due to security reason, i cant share the pdf. Shall i send the data for "pkcs7"?'* - Well, there is a *small chance* that one can identify the reason for validation failure from the signature container alone. Thus, you may try it. But be aware, it is more likely that the PDF is needed, too, to analyze the issue.

Comment: *"I have added the Signature container"* - no, you have added a dump of information in text form derived from the `PdfPKCS7` object. The least one requires for an analysis of your issue is the actual CMS signature container that `PdfPKCS7` object represents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174013/discussion-between-learner-and-mkl).

Comment: I have added a piece of code [in the chat room of your question](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174013/discussion-between-learner-and-mkl). Please use it to extract the signature container in question and post it.

Comment: I had a look at the data you posted. A `DigestAlgorithmOid` "1.2.840.10040.4.3" is very weird as that OID is for SHA1withDSA, i.e. a signature algorithm. In combination with that a `DigestEncryptionAlgorithmOid` "1.3.36.3.3.1.2" is also weird because that OID is for RipeMD160withRSA, i.e. your signature is unclear about the hash algorithm (SHA1? RipeMD160?) and the signature algorithm (DSA? RSA?) used. Whether this is an issue of the signature container or of `PdfPKCS7` I cannot tell without the former.

Comment: Signature Signature1 
SubFilter /adbe.x509.rsa_sha1 
Content BIIBAHWe55P55rAOY7xoVquC0kJHRQkHqasvz6po/2p1vTkYxzngR8UN6CMKcrb6srZjhrr+7HH+s//08OxzeUg01sAFEerZ7bals7zm39F4keYBitkQXuYlrxw6TuSTvANwO5bs7mXw8VozrxbH8q6JyNOqd/eqycuWJUtapcDqUn+AoH0UJFUtdq2EXEbT2tVeFpSIKmYdWK6w3YcOFSNBF+JYiRoFCLHJKRCNNjV2bFW3c+72lJ4qF40OoeQ1Sj9Pr+BUzM1XTt2tT4GBzdCDlzaPLEhAZd8rJrVVNNXurkAu19h/5WvxLlQc5enM4ILX1DbdnOCkTgaSdYNkvV72QrsAAAAAAAA........                                       The Signature container..  Remaining are the long string of A's as to be in base64

Comment: Arg, a `adbe.x509.rsa_sha1` signature. (You are aware that these signatures have been deprecated in PDF-2?) 
First of all, the work-around updating the RSAdata is not applicable here; probably it damages something but it does no good.
Other than that, though, I cannot do any kind of analysis of this kind of signature without the whole signed document.

Comment: When I said that there was a small chance to identify the cause of the validation failure, I thought the signature was a `adbe.pkcs7.detached` or `ETSI.CAdES.detached` type. In that case the signature container comes with enough internal structure and information to analyze to find some causes of validation failures. `adbe.x509.rsa_sha1` are different.