# iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.Verify() returns false while the pdf documnet was not modified since signed

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, verify

[image: C# code][image]I use the Verify function to verify that a digital signed pdf document was not modified since signed. Sometimes, the Verify function returns false, which means that the document was modified, while the Acrobat Reader displays an opposite message.
While debugging the program, I discovered 2 inner fields of PdfPKCS7 class, "verified" and "verifyResult". Before calling Verify function, both were FALSE. After the calling, "verified" was TRUE while "verifyResult" remained FALSE.
There are 2 questions:

1. Why Verify returned false while the document was not modified?
2. Why "verified" field was true while Verify returned false?

Comment: `verified` is an internal field to indicate if the verification result has been calculated, it does not indicate if the document is valid or not. [Source code](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/PdfPKCS7.cs). If it's false, then it calculates and `Verify()` returns the `verifyResult`, if it's true, it returns the previously calculated `verifyResult`.

Comment: Also, you should use [iText7](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) instead of iTextSharp for new projects, since [iTextSharp is EOL and has been replaced by iText7](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp)

Comment: Thanks Magnetron!! You answered my second question. The real problem is the first one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not familiar with it to answer, that's why I posted as a comment. But try iText7 and see if you get the same results, it could be a bug that was fixed, but again, I'm not very familiar to answer. [It could also be this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846427/pdfpkcs7-verify-return-false)

Comment: To analyze the issue, please share an example PDF for which validation fails. You say validation fails "sometimes" - does that really mean that for the same file sometimes validation succeeds and sometimes fails? Or do you actually mean that for some PDFs validation fails unexpectedly while for other files it succeeds as expected?

Comment: Thanks, @Magnetron. The link you gave is a post of mkl, but that case does not help me.

Comment: Thanks @mkl. I read your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846427/pdfpkcs7-verify-return-false), but as I saw in debugger, the RSAdata field of PdfPKCS7 object is NULL and stil, the Verify function returns FALSE, so, I guess, your advise wouldn't help. I wrote SOMETIMES, because not every PDF failes, only about 30% of them. I cannot attach a PDF doc due to security reasons.

Comment: I'm afraid without a signed document to analyze, I cannot analyze.

Comment: I will check if I can export one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to G-D the problem was solved by UPGRADING iText from version 5 to 7. Thanks to whom was concerned about it.

Comment: While it is indeed a good idea to switch from itext 5 to itext 7, this does not automatically fix problems. Most likely there was an issue in your itext 5 based setup which is not in your itext 7 based one.